# Scrollpath not working properly with arrow keys

Tags: jquery, navigation, html5-canvas

I'm trying to use the [scrollpath](https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath) plugin, but I'm experiencing a strange behavior when I try to use the down arrow key to navigate the page.

This is the script:

```
function init() {

$.fn.scrollPath("getPath")
.moveTo(600, 50, {name: 'inizio'})
.lineTo(600, 2300, {name: "myPath"})
.lineTo(1800, 1300, {name: "myPath2"});

$(".wrapper").scrollPath({drawPath: true, wrapAround: true});
}
```

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fYrFT/5/) to better show the problem.

The fact is that the script seems correct, since if I just scroll with the mouse it works as expected, but when I use the down key it I see that at some point the view stops scrolling down and then it doesn't really follow the path.

Another strange thing is that using the up key it works fine, but in the opposite direction.

Comment: It works perfectly for me in Chrome and IE 10

Comment: That's true, I didn't try that. Still, I'd like it to work on Firefox too.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the plugin, not your code.  You should contact the plugin author to see if they have a fix (although the script has not been updated in 1+ years):  http://joelb.me/blog/contact/